# Why Mapkit Mapview on start zoom buttons flicker?

Tags: dictionary, huawei-mobile-services

set zoom buttons are disabled in xml ,

```
map:uiZoomControls="false"
```

i expect zoom buttons NOT to appear, But When I launch app with Huawei maps mapview, zoom buttons appear for about 0.5 seconds and only then become invisible, So how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add the code below to your activity or fragment:

```
mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

@Override
public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap huaweiMap) {
    huaweiMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
}
```

Could show more code about your xml and Fragment/Activity if problem still.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to change the map zoom control UI settings:

[Setting Attributes Using the Layout File](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001061993581__section10810213187)

[Setting Attributes Using the Code File](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001061993581__section55412018141915)

The first way is to change the map fragment/activity layout xml file to add code as follows. Make sure the map namespace is declared

```
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

map:uiZoomControls="false"
```

The 2nd way is to change the UiSettings ZoomControls code:

```
hMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

I have an app integrated HMS Map and tested both ways to hide the zoom buttons successfully. I am using Huawei Mate 30 Pro for app testing and have not seen the zoom buttons anytime.